# App crashes if checkbox isn't clicked before button is pressed

Tags: android, button, checkbox

My app works in terms of navigation whilst the check box is ticked, but of course in the use of the app the check box will not always be checked and accounts for something else instead.

I need to be able for the the Go button to work regardless of the state of the check box.

I managed to get the code to work but now it has begun to close down again whenever the button is clicked and the pin box does not display when the check box is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        GoBtn = findViewById(R.id.GoBtn);
        GoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //method called
        if (v == checkBox){
            if (checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                userPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //when checkbox is check, userPin becomes visible
            }
        }
        else if (v == GoBtn){
            ChangeActivityStudent();
        }
        {
            userPin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //otherwise userPin is invisible
        }

        // called when check box is clicked

        GoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ChangeActivityStudent();
            }
        });
   }
    private void ChangeActivityStudent(){
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Where is "GoBtn" initialization and what is the error crash you are getting?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserName = findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        userPassword = findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        userPin = findViewById(R.id.userPin);
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        GoBtn = findViewById(R.id.GoBtn);
there is no error the app just crashes on the emulator if the gobtn is pressed before the check box is checkes

Answer (score 1):

You're setting an `onClickListener` on `GoBtn` inside another `onClickListener()`. This means that the `onClickListener` on `GoBtn` won't be set until you clicked on the CheckBox. Replace your `onClick()` method with this:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == checkBox){
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
            {
                userPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //when checkbox is check, userPin becomes visible
            }
    }else if(v == GoBtn){
    ChangeActivityStudent();
    }

}
```

And set listener for both buttons in your `onCreate()`.

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
GoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Moreover, I don't think you should be setting `onClickListener` on `checkBox` since its a checked button. And you might need to get the checkbox state. The best method to use is `CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `GoBtn.setOnClickListener` is in the wrong location. 
 It shouldn't be inside `onClick(View v)` method.
Currently you are applying logic to the button click only after the checkBox is clicked.
That's probably not what causing your app to crash, but won't work if not changed.

What you need to do is move the `GoBtn.setOnClickListener` next to where you call `checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);` 
if you want cause a click programmatically, call `GoBtn.performClick()`.